# How to display images from multiple folders AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop

I am trying to display images from 3 folders named `FOLDER1`, `FOLDER2`, and `FOLDER3`. I am trying to use a `for loop` to loop through each folder incrementally and display each of their contents in separate divs categorized under their corresponding folder names. But the code I have is unable to do that. For some reason, the for loop only loops through the `FOLDER3` folder and completely skips `FOLDER1` and `FOLDER2` despite the *content file names* of `FOLDER1` and `FOLDER2` being displayed as broken images (which is so confusing)! Maybe I'm missing a line I should be adding to my AJAX code to make it work?

THIS is the result I would like to achieve:

```
FOLDER1
images/FOLDER1/folder1_img.jpg

FOLDER2
images/FOLDER2/folder2_img.jpg

FOLDER3
images/FOLDER3/folder3_img.jpg
```

BUT - THIS is the result I *currently* have:

```
FOLDER1
images/FOLDER3/folder1_img.jpg

FOLDER2
images/FOLDER3/folder2_img.jpg

FOLDER3
images/FOLDER3/folder3_img.jpg
```

This is my complete code:

HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<body>
<div class="wflex">
    <div class="wscdfx">
        <?php $items = array("FOLDER1", "FOLDER2", "FOLDER3"); ?>
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <div class="spct"><?php echo "$item"; ?></div>
            <div class="prodfx"></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX script:

```
<script>
for (n = 1; n < 4; n++) {
    var folder = "images/FOLDER"+n+"/";

    $.ajax({
      url : folder,
      success: function (data) {
          $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
              if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                  $(".prodfx").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
              } 
          });
      }
  });
}
</script>
```

Please, if someone can help me here, I would GREATLY appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add async: false in ajax request.

Comment: okay but that gives me a problem - 3 images (one from each folder) are being grouped together and displayed underneath each folder. I only want images from their *own folders* to be grouped together.